# Adicionar interação no listview!

Tags: android, listview

Eu estou com um problema na minha *listview*. Estou listando todos os carros que o usuário tem, mas quando ele clicar eu quero pegar as informações desse carro para processar, só que nos tutoriais que eu vejo os caras fizeram uma *listview* usando uma classe que estendia do *arrayadapter* e eles usam um *array* pra pegar as informações, diferente do que eu tenho.

Gostaria de uma dica de como devo fazer. Minha classe onde tem a listagem:

```
package comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.carro.gui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.R;
import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.cliente.dominio.Cliente;
import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.cliente.gui.PrincipalClienteActivity;
import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.cliente.negocio.ClienteNegocio;
import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.infraestrutura.DatabaseHelper;
import comviewzonazul.google.httpssites.zonazul.usuario.negocio.UsuarioNegocio;

public class GerenciarCarroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    Cursor cursor;
    SimpleCursorAdapter ad;
    ListView lista;
    String login;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gerenciar_carro);
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LoginActivityPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        login             = preferences.getString("LOGIN", null);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        buscarDados();
        Listagem();
    }
    public int buscarIdCliente(){
        UsuarioNegocio usuarioNegocio = new UsuarioNegocio(getApplicationContext());
        int id_usuario = usuarioNegocio.pegarId(login);
        ClienteNegocio clienteNegocio = new ClienteNegocio(getApplicationContext());
        Cliente cliente = clienteNegocio.retornaCliente(id_usuario);
        return cliente.getId();
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
        if (database == null){
            database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return database;
    }

    public void buscarDados(){
        cursor = getDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA + ", A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.MODELO + ", A." + DatabaseHelper.Compra.ID + ", A."
                + DatabaseHelper.Carros.FABRICANTE + ", A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.COR +  " FROM " + DatabaseHelper.Carros.TABELA_CARROS
                + " as A INNER JOIN " + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.TABELA_CARROCLIENTE +
                " as B ON A." + DatabaseHelper.Carros.ID + " = B." + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CARRO
                + " WHERE B." + DatabaseHelper.CarroCliente.ID_CLIENTE + " = ?", new String[] {Integer.toString(buscarIdCliente())});

        if(cursor!=null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    }

    public void Listagem(){
        lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView_car);
        String[] from = { DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA, DatabaseHelper.Carros.FABRICANTE, DatabaseHelper.Carros.MODELO, DatabaseHelper.Carros.COR};
        int [] to = {R.id.placa, R.id.fabricante, R.id.modelo, R.id.cor};
        ad = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listar_carro,cursor,from,to);
        lista.setAdapter(ad);
    }

    public void remover(View view){
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), DatabaseHelper.Carros.PLACA, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void adicionar(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, AdicionarCarro.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }


    public void voltar(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, PrincipalClienteActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, eu te aconselho a utilizar um ArrayAdapter e ArrayList como vc mesmo citou acima, vai por mim, embora você possa achar meio complexo, é bem simples quando você começar a implementar, e se você vai realmente desenvolver para android mais cedo ou mais tarde terá que enfrentar os Adpters lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certo, você tem que ter valores já pré definidos para fazer o que quer. Por exemplo, se você clicar no valor de uma Ferrari no seu listview, ele consultar uma lista ou vetor que traga as informações que possuem baseado no parametro "Ferrari" entendeu ? E as adaptações feitas, são ListViews customizadas, onde você pode adicionar mais textos ou até mesmo imagens no seu listview.

No seu caso digamos você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
  lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Coloque esse trecho de código no seu onCreate na ultima linha, que quando você clicar irá aparecer um Toast com o item clicado.